# Adding views dynamically displays background only

Tags: android, android-layout

> I have used a linear layout which will have a top layout and bottom layout. The bottom layout is scrollview which has listview too.
> I have done it programmatically by adding layouts as follows,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.details);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    tpaydetail=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView39);
    back=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton31);
    share=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton41);
    amountdetail=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView29);
    intrstdetail=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView31);
    perioddetail=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView33);
    Memidetail=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView35);
    tintdetail=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView37);
    LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayouttop=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout8);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayoutbottom=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.forscrolling);
    RelativeLayout mainview=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrolltest);
    ScrollView s=new ScrollView(this);
    s.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mainview.removeAllViews();
    relativeLayoutbottom.removeAllViews();
    s.addView(relativeLayoutbottom);
    relativeLayouttop.removeAllViews();
    ll.addView(relativeLayouttop);
    ll.addView(s);
    setContentView(ll);
```

> And my xml code is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/scrolltest">
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="#3784ba"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout8">
    <ImageButton
        android:rotation="90"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/backarrow"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:background="#3784ba"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton31"/>
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="EMI Details"
        android:id="@+id/textView25"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <ImageButton
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sharenew"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:background="#3784ba"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton41"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/forscrolling"
android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout8"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@drawable/fortablein"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout9"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@drawable/fortablein"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Amount"
            android:id="@+id/textView28" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="-0.5dip"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@drawable/fortablein"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/textView29" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout9"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout10"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="-0.5dip"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@drawable/fortablein"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Interest %"
            android:id="@+id/textView30" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="-0.5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="-0.5dip"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@drawable/fortablein"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/textView31" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout10"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout11"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="-0.5dip"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@drawable/fortablein"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Period"
            android:id="@+id/textView32" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="-0.5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="-0.5dip"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@drawable/fortablein"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/textView33" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout11"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout12"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="-0.5dip"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@drawable/fortablein"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Monthly EMI"
            android:id="@+id/textView34" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="-0.5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="-0.5dip"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@drawable/fortablein"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/textView35" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/lll"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout12"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="-0.5dip"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@drawable/fortablein"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Total Interest"
            android:id="@+id/textView36" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="-0.5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="-0.5dip"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@drawable/fortablein"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/textView37" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lll"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="-0.5dip"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@drawable/fortablein"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Total Payment"
            android:id="@+id/textView38" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="-0.5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="-0.5dip"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@drawable/fortablein"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/textView39" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:background="#3784ba"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="Month"
        android:id="@+id/textView212" />
    <TextView
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
      android:text="Principal"
        android:id="@+id/textView222" />
    <TextView
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
       android:text="Interest"
        android:id="@+id/textView232" />
    <TextView
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="Balance"
        android:id="@+id/textView242" />
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> Here, the textviews used inside those layouts are not visible when i am running it. Is there a problem with my code? Guide me please.
>
> Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just setup the layout like you want it in the XML to begin with?

Comment: I have used listview inside scrollview. I am just trying to solve this problem. I thought "adding views dynamically may helps".That's why.

Comment: If you mean the problem is that a `ListView` doesn't really work inside a `ScrollView`, it won't. Anyway, we have no idea what the `details` layout looks like, so we can't really tell you what's happening when you shuffle all that around in your code there.

Comment: post your details.xml code here

Comment: I read some posts and I tried the solution **nestedscrollingEnabled=false** for that. It doesn't work for me. So I am trying a new way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all. Finally I found a solution:

I created separate layouts for top layout, relative layout which is above listview and listview. Then I added  **Relative layout as headerview to listview instead of using scrollview**  as follows,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    topview=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.details,null);
    scrollview=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.scrollingrelativelayout,null);
    listview=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listviewxml,null);
    lv=(ListView)listview.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    lv.addHeaderView(scrollview);
    LinearLayout forscrolltest=new LinearLayout(this);
    forscrolltest.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    forscrolltest.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    forscrolltest.addView(topview);
    forscrolltest.addView(lv);
    setContentView(forscrolltest);
```

> It is working. :)

Answer (score 0):

By default ListView is scrollable. Do not put ScrollView to the ListView. so remove scrollview and make list wrap content.

Happy coding!!

Comment: But I need the whole page should be scrolled.Not the listview only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make views dynamically then don't use `setContentView()` first in `onCreate` and if you want views then use LayoutInflater to inflate layout and then extract views from it.

With current code the issue I can see is `Activity` view is set twice resulting in too much work.

```
relativeLayoutbottom.removeAllViews();
```

Check the above line you are removing all views from layout and adding it to `ScrollView` i.e;   `s.addView(relativeLayoutbottom);`

Please check if your layout pass is headed correctly.